# Modifying content width of the Sphinx theme 'Read the Docs'

Tags: html, themes, width, python-sphinx

I am using 'Read the Docs' Sphinx theme for my documentation. In the original theme, given below

[Read the Docs Sphinx Theme](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

the content or main layout width is designed to be mobile friendly. However, for my project I would like this to be a bit more wide. I do not know HTML and hence would appreciate if any one could give me some clues to increase the content (layout) width.

Comment: In 2019, it is as simple as adding the required css via html_css_files option. Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57840173/466066

Comment: @hypersonics The link is broken. Perhaps you could update it?

Comment: @JamesHirschorn I have just updated. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Another option is to create a stylesheet in `source/_static` with just the css you want, e.g.

```
.wy-nav-content {
    max-width: none;
}
```

or

```
.wy-nav-content {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
}
```

Make sure the directory is referenced in `source/conf.py` - I believe by default there's a line to do this, i.e.

```
# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

Then create a custom layout in `source/_templates/layout.html` and do something like this to include your stylesheet

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <link href="{{ pathto("_static/style.css", True) }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

Assuming you called your stylesheet `style.css`

Comment: This was the solution I used. Is probably the best option if you are using ReadTheDocs for your build.

Answer (score 32):

In case someone is searching for a simpler answer...
combining the ideas from
https://samnicholls.net/2016/06/15/how-to-sphinx-readthedocs/
and the above suggestions, I found the easiest way of getting a custom window-width is the following:

1. In `conf.py`, add a function that adds a custom stylesheet:

   ```py
   def setup(app):
       app.add_css_file('my_theme.css')
   ```
2. In `conf.py`, state/adjust:

   ```py
   html_static_path = ['_static']
   ```
3. Create a `_static` folder/directory if it doesn't exist.
4. Create a file called `my_theme.css` in the `_static` folder that contains the lines:

   ```css
   .wy-nav-content {
       max-width: 1200px !important;
   }
   ```

Comment: Simplest choice and it worked locally and on gitlab pages.

Answer (score 26):

The HTML option added in Sphinx 1.8.0b1 (released Sep 2018) simplifies the process. The [recommendation](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html#adding-custom-css-or-javascript) in Read The Docs Documentation is [adding custom css](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/adding-custom-css.html) to the theme via the `html_css_files` option in **conf.py**.

```
html_css_files = [
    'custom.css',
]
```

Put the custom.css in the html static path folder (Default is **_static** folder).

Content of **custom.css**:

```
.wy-nav-content {
    max-width: 75% !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. Just note that the name of the style is **w**y-nav-content, not my-nav-content, as I first thought.

Answer (score 18):

First of all I must say, that during my sphinx **quickstart** I chose the option of separate folder for my **sources** and for my **build**.

It's a 3 steps process:

### 1. Create a document for your styles:

Where?

1. In the same directory where my `conf.py` lives, (in my case `source`), I created a folder for my custom static files (stylesheets, javascripts). I called it `custom`.
2. Inside it I created a subfolder for my stylesheets: `source/custom/css`.
3. In this subfolder I'm gonna create my custom styles: `source/custom/css/my_theme.css`.

### 2. Telling sphinx about it

Now we have to tell sphinx to spit this document inside `build/_static/css`, the same directory where is the stylesheet included in the **Read The Documents** theme. We do that adding the following line to `conf.py`:

```
html_static_path = ['custom']       # Directory for static files.
```

Done. Now, if we build, we will have the **RTD** styles (`theme.css`), and our custom `my_theme.css` in the same directory, `build/_static/css`.

### 3. Selecting our custom theme

Now we are gonna tell sphinx to use our custom `my_theme.css`, instead of the **RTD** one. We do that adding this line in `conf.py`:

```
html_style = 'css/my_theme.css'     # Choosing my custom theme.
```

In our custom stylesheet, the first line should import the styles of `theme.css` with `@import url("theme.css");`.

And we are ready to start overwriting styles.

## UPDATE: THERE IS AN EVEN SIMPLER WAY.

### 1. Put your customizations inside `source/_static/css/my_theme.css`.

In your custom stylesheet, the first line should import the styles of `theme.css` with `@import url("theme.css");`.

This way, you don't have to worry about messing up the default styles, if your **custom stylesheet** doesn't work, delete and start again.

### 2. Add the following line in `conf.py`:

```
html_style = 'css/my_theme.css'
```

Comment: thanks for pointing @import. It's the least-hackish way to add new stylesheet to RTD theme

Comment: this only works in local builds. If I publish my docs to the website, it won't load the .css

Comment: Note: This will *not* work with a hyphen in the file (i.e. my-theme.css).

Answer (score 7):

The solutions here are somewhat hackish.  If you want to include the style, and have a css override and have it work on RTD you will want something like this.

```
on_rtd = os.environ.get('READTHEDOCS', None) == 'True'

if not on_rtd:  # only import and set the theme if we're building docs locally
  import sphinx_rtd_theme
  html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
  html_theme_path = [sphinx_rtd_theme.get_html_theme_path()]
  html_style = 'css/custom.css'
else:
  html_context = { 
    'css_files': [
        'https://media.readthedocs.org/css/sphinx_rtd_theme.css',
        'https://media.readthedocs.org/css/readthedocs-doc-embed.css',
        '_static/css/custom.css',
    ],  
  }
```

I have tested this myself and it appears to work locally and on RTD.  Largely plagiarized from https://blog.deimos.fr/2014/10/02/sphinxdoc-and-readthedocs-theme-tricks-2/

Answer (score 7):

1. source\conf.py

```py
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_style = 'css/my_theme.css'
```

2. source\_static\css\my_theme.css

```css
@import url("theme.css");

.wy-nav-content {
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

That will be 90% width of your monitor.

Comment: This helped! I was trying to use default alabaster theme and nothing I did could make the display wider.  As soon as I followed this example and changed theme to 'sphinx_rtd_theme', then the result was both much nicer to look at and used whole browser width. Whew.

Answer (score 7):

I found myself repeating this customization on multiple projects I've worked on (based on the great answers here, of course  ).

So I made an extension just for that, the usage is as follows:

`pip install sphinx-rtd-size`

And in the conf.py:

```
    extensions = [
        ...
        'sphinx_rtd_size',
    ]
    
    sphinx_rtd_size_width = "90%"
```

Hoping this might simplify things for future users...

You can checkout the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-rtd-size) and the [github repository](https://github.com/tadnir/sphinx-rtd-size).

Edit 1:

Clarification - This extension is only relevant for the theme "sphinx_rtd_theme".

Comment: Thank you!! The straightforward answer we all needed. Works like a charm

Comment: I do not know if you have the same issue, but when using the viewcode extension, the source code is not displayed using the requested size width.

Comment: I like this idea, but the output doesn't work as I expected, any thing I can verify in final html `  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9, maximum-scale=0.9" />` ?

Comment: aha, better to mention, it use theme 'sphinx_rtd_theme' (i tried with default alabaster, which doesn't work), now I am happy

Comment: after installing, i'm getting `exception: No module named 'sphinx_rtd_size'`

Comment: Please create an issue in the linked github page with steps to reproduce (including sphinx, rtd packages versions used) and I'll try to help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

For 'classic' Theme, The solution is as simple and as clean as :

```
# Add/Update "html_theme_options" like this on your conf.py
html_theme_options = {'body_max_width': '70%'}
```

Adapt the percentage to your taste.

> Reference from sphinx: body_max_width (int or str): Maximal width of the document body. This can be an int, which is interpreted as pixels or a valid CSS dimension string such as ‘70em’ or ‘50%’. Use ‘none’ if you don’t want a width limit. Defaults may depend on the theme (often 800px).

Answer (score 4):

To make the [ReadTheDocs](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/theme.html) theme use the entire width of your screen you can modify the [`theme.css`](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/blob/master/media/css/sphinx_rtd_theme.css) file, removing the `max-width: 800px;` property from the `wy-nav-content` class definition, like so:

```
.wy-nav-content {
    padding: 1.618em 3.236em;
    height: 100%;
    /* max-width: 800px; */
    margin: auto;
}
```

---

### Some Notes

- Source of [`theme.css`](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/blob/master/media/css/sphinx_rtd_theme.css) is here:

  https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/blob/master/media/css/sphinx_rtd_theme.css
- On your filesystem it will be in (assuming you've run:`pip install sphinx_rtd_theme`):

  `lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css/theme.css`
- To find the absolute path of [`theme.css`](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/blob/master/media/css/sphinx_rtd_theme.css) on Linux/Mac you can run this on the command line (assuming you have set your `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable):

  ```sh
  for p in `echo $PYTHONPATH | tr ":" "\n"`; do 
      find $p -type f -name 'theme.css' | grep sphinx_rtd_theme
  done
  ```
- The [`theme.css`](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/blob/master/media/css/sphinx_rtd_theme.css) file will be minified so you can use a tool like http://unminify.com to make it easier to read.

---

### The results:

#### Before:

[image: Unmodified readthedocs theme]

#### After:

[image: Modified readthedocs theme]

Answer (score 1):

I would modify this in the css.  You should search for the file theme.css (it is in the read-the-doc sources at "sphinx_rtd_theme/static/css/theme.css").

Make a copy of that file and put it in your sphinx _static dir.  In that css file you can make all the layout changes that you need.  (You might have to read a bit on css files if you have never worked with that.)

Hope this helps.