# How do I set up custom styles for reStructuredText, Sphinx, ReadTheDocs, etc.?

Tags: css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I want to extend the theme used by *Sphinx* and *ReadTheDocs* with my own custom styles.

What is the best way I can do this so that my changes will stick?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462494/how-to-add-custom-css-file-to-sphinx

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Edit: as of 2021 the following answer is outdated, please use `html_css_files = []` in your `conf.py` instead of using the application API after version 1.8 (current Sphinx version at time of writing is 4.1.1). The `add_stylesheet` option below has been renamed `add_css_file` in version 1.8, and seems more intended for Sphinx extension developers.

### Assumptions

Your RTD doc set has something like the following structure:

- *(root path)*

  - *(some other stuff not germane to this discussion)*
  - `_static/`
  - `_templates/`
  - `conf.py`

You're also building locally using `sphinx-build` or `sphinx-autobuild` using the default theme, but your deployed server might use the `sphinx-rtd-theme` instead.

### Use Case: Hatnotes

For this illustration, I'm going to show how to create custom styling for "hatnotes", a concept which is prevalent in MediaWiki docs and which corresponds *roughly* to the `admonition` construct in RST. You can apply what's shown here to create any custom CSS and include it in your doc set.

### Step 1: Create Custom CSS

The custom CSS file should go somewhere under the `_static/` directory, as that's where the build process and scripts will find it. I would encourage a `css/` subdirectory, since you might have other customizations to add, like JavaScript files.

Create your custom CSS file and put it in this directory. Write your style specifications as an overlay to whatever might already exist in the theme you'll be using in the build. Also don't assume anything about whether your style will override an existing style in the theme, as you can't guarantee when your styles will be added in relation to the default ones.

Here's my custom CSS for hatnotes. I saved this at `_static/css/hatnotes.css`.

```css
.hatnote
{
    border-color: #c8c8c8 ;
    border-style: solid ;
    border-width: 1px ;
    font-size: x-small ;
    font-style: italic ;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    padding: 3px 2em ;
}
.hatnote-gray { background-color: #e8e8e8 ; color: #000000 ; }
.hatnote-yellow { background-color: #ffffe8 ; color: #000000 ; }
.hatnote-red { background-color: #ffe8e8 ; color: #000000 ; }
.hatnote-icon { height: 16px ; width: 16px ; }
```

### Step 2: Add Styles to Templates

For the default theme, it is sufficient to create a template that overrides the default `layout.html` to add your custom CSS to the layout. Use of templates is well documented [at sphinxdoc.org](http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html#configuration-variables). In your override template, simply set the `css-files` variable (an array) with an appended list of your custom CSS files.

Here is my template which adds the hatnotes CSS. I saved this as `_templates/layout.html`.

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% set css_files = css_files + [ "_static/css/hatnotes.css" ] %}
```

That's all you need to do for the default theme. For the Sphinx/RTD theme, there's an additional step, where you…

### Step 3: Add Stylesheets to the Theme

For the Sphinx/RTD theme, your template will be ignored. Instead of using the template mechanism, you have to add a function to your `conf.py` file which adds the CSS file to the app's theme. Somewhere near where your conf file sets the `html_theme` attribute, add something like the following:

```python
def setup(app):
  app.add_stylesheet( "css/hatnotes.css" )
```

Note that, this time, there's no `_static/` at the front of the path; the `add_stylesheet()` function assumes that part of the path.

### Finishing the Use Case

Now that you've set up your custom styles for both the default theme and the Sphinx/RTD theme, you can actually use them in your doc.

Following the usual paradigm of defining stock hatnotes as "templates" in MediaWiki (sorry, not the same as templates in Sphinx and RTD), I set up an `includes/` directory where all my hatnotes would be stored.

Here's how to construct a hatnote with the custom style information. This file is `includes/hatnotes/stub-article.rst`.

```
.. container:: hatnote hatnote-gray

   |stub| This article is a stub. Please improve the docs by expanding it.

.. |stub| image:: /images/icons/stub.png
          :class: hatnote-icon
```

Here we set up our "stub" hatnote to have the default hatnote styling, the gray background, and use a "stub" icon as the inline image, with the `hatnote-icon` style applied to that image.

Now we can use the file as an included resource in a document.

```
Foo Article
===========

.. include:: /includes/hatnotes/stub-article.rst

Blah blah I haven't written this article yet.
```

Whether you're using the local default theme or the Sphinx/RTD theme, the hatnote will be rendered with the styles you added by setting up the `_templates/layout.html` template and the `conf.py` script to both include the custom  CSS file you put under the `_static/` directory.

### End State

Your doc repository now has this stuff in it:

- *(root path)*

  - `_static/`

    - `css/`

      - *(custom CSS files…)*
  - `_templates/`

    - `layout.html` — *(adds your custom CSS to the default layout)*
  - `conf.py` — *(with new function to add custom CSS to app's theme)*

Comment: well done answer but I think there is a typo in template example (`{% set css_files = css_files + [ "_static/css/hatnotes/css" ] %}`); last `/` should be a dot?

Comment: Thanks for setting out all the steps! Spent quite a bit of time fiddling with each of the options and they didn't work separately.

Comment: This is awesome.  The only update is that you should use `app.add_css_file(...)` as  `app. add_stylesheet(...)` has been deprecated.

Comment: Edited this post with an update at the top as the advice is deprecated/intended for extension developers, but not edited the body of this answer. Left a separate answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68394150/2668831) with current advice

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which is most "official" but if you go to the ["customisation"](https://pradyunsg.me/furo/customisation/) page of the Furo theme (developed by one of the Sphinx developers) and then scroll to "Custom CSS Files" it links to a guide to ["injecting code"](https://pradyunsg.me/furo/customisation/injecting/#injecting-code) which in turn simply links out to ReadTheDocs's page on [Adding Custom CSS](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html) which does not suggest running Python code (as the answers above do) but setting a conf variable, which seems better.

```py
html_css_files = [
    'css/custom.css',
]
```

Comment: Neat! I'm guessing this probably wasn't available in 2015 when I originally posted the question. If it works then this is clearly the cleaner solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the answer above is [deprecated](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_css_file), not sure if you can un-accept it now. `add_stylesheet` is renamed to `add_css_file` in Sphinx version 1.8 and note that this is the "application API" (i.e. for extensions to interact with directly). The `html_css_files` option was also added in version 1.8, so I think `conf.py` is now the preferred approach. I'll edit the answer above

Comment: I found that the trailing list-comma was necessary for the file to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer: There are various other approaches for this, e.g. [adding to footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211695/modifying-content-width-of-the-sphinx-theme-read-the-docs) or [adding to extrahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211695/modifying-content-width-of-the-sphinx-theme-read-the-docs). The latter is [recommended by the RTD docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#blocks).

Also I found the `setup()` function was never necessary, as long as you have `html_static_path = ['_static']` in your `conf.py`.

Note that normally, you should replace the absolute path `[ "_static/css/hatnotes.css" ]` with `[ pathto("_static/css/hatnotes.css", True) ]` or the style sheet will not be loaded for RST files inside subdirectories, but it is evidently unnecessary for the accepted answer. Not sure why.