# Sphinx Alabaster font - what is the settings of standard libraries?

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using the `alabaster` theme in `sphinx` but still can't get the standard font look like [Falcon](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/api.html) and [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/).

Looking at [`falcon`'s `conf.py`](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/blob/master/docs/conf.py) I couldn't find any font related `html_theme_options` so I wonder how those two libraries keep a unified font style which is not the default.
I also tried using [`falcon`'s `custom.css`](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/blob/master/docs/_static/custom.css) - But that didn't work either.

What should I set in `conf.py` in order to get this exact font look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falcon used a [non-standard method of overriding the default theme's style sheet](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/blob/master/docs/_templates/sidebar-top.html#L1).  I don't recommend this method.

You can either override the theme's default CSS or the theme's template files. Details of how to do so are answered in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32079202/2214933).