# restructuredtext font size without access to sphinx configuration

Tags: restructuredtext

our organization uses a custom command wrapper around Sphinx. It takes an RST file and outputs HTML and PDF using Sphinx under the hood.
But i do not have access to any underlying Sphinx configuration files.

Is there any way changing font size in restructuredtext without access to theme file?
I thought about cssclass maybe has some options?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up custom styles for reStructuredText, Sphinx, ReadTheDocs, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079200/how-do-i-set-up-custom-styles-for-restructuredtext-sphinx-readthedocs-etc)

Comment: I don't have access to the custom wrapper script around Sphinx so i can't add extensions myself. I thought there should be some existing default construct in restructuredtext to increase or decrease default font size?

Comment: There is no such feature. You must modify the theme.

Comment: Thanks - the documentation administrator confirmed that your suggestion of setting up custom style is the recommended way and he will help me to set that environment.