# How to link duplicate targets in reStructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I have two duplicate keys -> `.. command:: targetName` in my doc on two separate pages. I need to know how can I link to these two separate targets using the following syntax:

```
Page-1 Click this -> :command:`targetName`  # this will always open the first targetName declared in the doc
```

Goal:

```
Page-1 Click this -> :command:`targetName <page-1.html#targetName>`  # not working :/
Page-2 Click this -> :command:`targetName <page-2.html#targetName>`  # not working :/
Page-2 Click this -> `targetName <page-2.html#targetName>`_  # this will work but I don't want to use hyperlink instead of " :command: " cuz I want to keep my block style as is.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some terminology. What you call `targetName` is called `title` in reStructuredText.  The stuff in angle brackets is the `target`.  See [Cross-referencing syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#xref-syntax).

reStructuredText does not support nested inline markup, which includes styling hyperlinks. However there is a workaround with [replacement](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#replace).

> As reStructuredText doesn't support nested inline markup, the only way to create a reference with styled text is to use substitutions with the "replace" directive:
>
> ```
> I recommend you try |Python|_.
>
> .. |Python| replace:: Python, *the* best language around
> .. _Python: http://www.python.org/
> ```

In your case:

```
Page-1 Click this -> |myTarget|_

.. |myTarget| replace:: ``targetName``
.. _myTarget: page-1.html#targetName
```

For further customization of the appearance, use a custom style. See [How do I set up custom styles for reStructuredText, Sphinx, ReadTheDocs, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079200/how-do-i-set-up-custom-styles-for-restructuredtext-sphinx-readthedocs-etc) for one example.

Comment: this is great!! but the text color is somehow set to red instead of black. Any idea to set this text in black ? Please see the screenshot I included the snippet of the goal and along with code. https://paste.pics/30489ccb92a1b1299c8db6af10e5bae6

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please accept it and upvote it if it satisfies your requirements.