# Don't Display Read the Docs Sphinx TOC in Narrow Windows

Tags: html, windows, themes, width, python-sphinx

With a narrow window the full Read the Docs window displays content but when the window is widened a Table of Contents appears as a sidebar and the content is less than half the window width. How can the setting be changed so the window must be wider before the TOC is displayed?

I expect this [framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626140/4539999) with a stylesheet, conf.py reference and custom layout would work with the appropriate css in the `source/_static` stylesheet. Changing:

```
.wy-nav-content {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
}
```

I assume this involves testing if screen width less than a certain value then set `display_toc` to false. Something like:

```
/* Set to display toc */
body {
  display_toc: true;
}

/* On narrow screens, set don't display toc */
@media screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  body {
    display_toc: false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sphinx_rtd_theme version 0.4.3 **theme.css** seems to support:

- small screen with max-width: 480px
- medium screen with max-width: 768px
- and larger screens

I extracted the `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)` code and added it with a new width as shown below. (I don't know css so there may be more efficient code.)

Following this [process](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/adding-custom-css.html), put a **custom.css** file in the `html_static_path` folder (Default is **_static**) with just the required css, e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 950px){
    .wy-body-for-nav{background:#fcfcfc}
    .wy-nav-top{display:block}
    .wy-nav-side{left:-300px}
    .wy-nav-side.shift{width:85%;left:0}
    .wy-side-scroll{width:auto}
    .wy-side-nav-search{width:auto}
    .wy-menu.wy-menu-vertical{width:auto}
    .wy-nav-content-wrap{margin-left:0}
    .wy-nav-content-wrap
    .wy-nav-content{padding:1.618em}
    .wy-nav-content-wrap.shift{position:fixed;min-width:100%;left:85%;top:0;height:100%;overflow:hidden}
}
```

Change  **conf.py** to add `html_css_files` option for the **custom.css**:

```
html_css_files = ['custom.css']
```