# How to set the width at which the layout is switched to mobile layout, in Sphinx theme Read the Docs?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

The title is my question and i searched the web and the doc of rtd but may be i did not know for what exactly i am looking because i am not a web-tech specialist.

I want to achieve that the toggle to the mobile layout appears earlier, at a wider width. I only need to increase the value by a few 100px.

Comment: To override styles, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63820734/2214933

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't Display Read the Docs Sphinx TOC in Narrow Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821489/dont-display-read-the-docs-sphinx-toc-in-narrow-windows)