# Modifying content width of Jupyter book, or the Sphinx theme sphinx-book-theme

Tags: css, themes, width, python-sphinx, jupyterbook

I am using `jupyter-book` which by default uses the `sphinx-book-theme`.

There is a left sidebar, the content in the middle column and a right sidebar. I would like to make the content column wider.

This was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211695/modifying-content-width-of-the-sphinx-theme-read-the-docs) for the `readthedocs-theme`, but I'm not sure what style name to use here.

Comment: You will have to override at least `media (min-width: 768px)
#main-content {
    max-width: 70%;
}` and either or both left or right columns to adjust it to your preference.

Comment: The setting you gave seems to have no effect.

Comment: Did you also adjust the left or right column width?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what I'm doing since I don't know `css`. I copied the sidebar adjustment from someone else's repo. 

I have published a test book on github. Here is my [`custom.css`](https://github.com/quantitative-technologies/jupyter-book-issue/blob/gh-pages/_static/custom.css).

Comment: Try also `@media (min-width: 720px)
.col-md-3 {
    flex: 0 0 45%;
    max-width: 45%;
}`

Comment: I put your last comment as the entire `custom.css` but it did not have any visible effect. 

(I also pushed the update to my github where you can see the result.)

Comment: I see only one CSS entry, not two. You need both at least.

Comment: I put both, if I understood you correctly. Still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The following style in `_static/css/custom.css` creates a wider content container for `jupyterbook=0.12.1` using `pydata-sphinx-theme.css`.

To find the class names I used the "Inspect Elements" menu to display and highlight (by hovering the mouse cursor over the elements) the classes for the containers holding the sidebars and primary content (article).

```
/* -- .bd-container and .bd-container__inner both need to adjust ---------- */
/* -- this so 'outer container' grows with browser (no L/R 'dead space') -- */
.bd-container {
    max-width: 99%;
}

/* -- this so the 'inner container' fills the outer container -------------- */
.bd-container .bd-container__inner {
    max-width: 99%;
}

/* -- .bd-article-container holds the "text in the middle" (notebook / md) ------ */
/* -- width is as high as as 100 "ems" (characters) wide, scales with font size -*/
.bd-main .bd-content .bd-article-container {
    max-width: 100em;
}
```